# Como fazer para um objeto não ser criado no mapa em cima de outro objeto?

Tags: construct-2

Eu tenho um objeto que é criado aleatoriamente pelo mapa, e isso faz ele ser criado em cima dos outros objetos do mapa...
Como fazer para ele não ser criado em cima desses outros objetos, mas apenas onde o mapa estiver vazio?

Answer (score 0):

1 - A solução seria você criar um objeto (`Sprite`) do mesmo tamanho do seu personagem que verifica se ele está em cima de outro objeto antes dele "`spawnar`" o seu objeto principal.

2 - Pra isso você pode criar um grupo para os objetos que não podem ficar de baixo e depois fazer o `verificador` `verificar` xD

3 - Se `Object is Overlaping Another Object` no caso o "`Grupo de Objetos`" então o seu "`verificador`" randomiza novamente.